# Single array with size more than 100 becomes multiple array after building JSON through Jbuilder in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, json, reactjs, jbuilder

I have a table which has more than 100 records, When I try to retrieve the records using `where` method, I get a single array of length more than 100.

But after building JSON and when it reaches front end, I get two arrays instead of one. One array with size of 100 and other one with rest of the elements. Is it because of jbuilder or is JSON have a specific limit it can hold?

**in controller**

```
def index

    @screen_seat_type = ScreenSeatType.find_by screen_id: params[:screen_id], seat_type_id: params[:seat_type_id]
    @seats = Seat.where( :screen_seat_type_id => @screen_seat_type.id ).order(:name)

  end
```

**in index.json.jbuilder**

```
json.seats @seats do |seat|
    json.id seat.id
    json.name seat.name
    json.row_name seat.row_name
    json.is_open seat.is_open
end
```

I'm using Rails API + ReactJS.

Comment: How you determined size of the array returned? Can you please put the result also in your question

Comment: @SandeepGarg i have checked seats before passing it to json.jbuilder. i can send the screenshot of network log from browser

Comment: Ohh... in network logs you are seeing two arrays because it truncate any huge array and any one wants to see whole array then he can expand that one. Actually it is only one array not two

Comment: Thank you @SandeepGarg. It was so confusing when i checked network logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In network logs you are seeing two arrays because it truncate any huge array and any one wants to see whole array then he can expand that one. Actually it is only one array not two